# BCL classes not found when rendering view in ASP.NET Core 1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get a basic ASP.NET MVC Core 1 project up and running (packages from `aspnetcidev` feed, DNX SDK `1.0.0-rc2-16551`). I got as far as running Kestrel for that project but when I try to navigate to `Home/Index` I'm greeted with a host of runtime errors:

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
3g0a2dps.mjy(4,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(5,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(6,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(7,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(8,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(11,50): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(11,91): error CS1980: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
3g0a2dps.mjy(11,91): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(19,16): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(19,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(19,63): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(21,16): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(21,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(21,79): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(23,16): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(23,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(23,75): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(25,16): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(25,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Microsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(25,63): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(25,63): error CS1980: Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
3g0a2dps.mjy(25,63): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(25,84): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(30,36): error CS1983: The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>
3g0a2dps.mjy(30,31): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
3g0a2dps.mjy(30,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Task' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
3g0a2dps.mjy(30,36): error CS0115: 'ASPV__Views_Home_Index_cshtml.ExecuteAsync()': no suitable method found to override
```

and so on. It seems Razor is missing the BCL classes but at this point I have no idea how to provide those.

Here's my `project.json`:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "compilationOptions": {
      "emitEntryPoint": true,
      "warningsAsErrors": true,
      "preserveCompilationContext": true
   },

   "tools": {
      "dotnet-publish-iis": "1.0.0-*",
      "dotnet-razor-tooling": "1.0.0-*"
   },

   "content": [
      "Areas",
      "Views",
      "wwwroot",
      "hosting.json",
      "config.json"
   ],

   "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.WebListener": "0.1.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*",
      "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-*"
   },

   "commands": {
      "web": "MyApp"
   },

   "frameworks": {
      "dnx451": { }
   },

   "exclude": [
      "wwwroot",
      "node_modules"
   ],
   "publishExclude": [
      "**.user",
      "**.vspscc"
   ]
}
```

and this is my `global.json`:

```
{
   "projects": [ "src" ],
   "sdk": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-16551"
   }
}
```

The current MusicStore example app doesn't work for me (lots of missing references), so that is not much help either.

Has anybody got an idea where to pick up from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the latest MVC RC2 nightly builds with DNX, you must reference a compatibility package named `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Dnx` and call `services.AddMvcDnx()` from your `ConfigureServices()` method.

Read https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/154 for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that eventually did the trick. I had to add `"Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-rc2-*"` as well though, to get this to work.