# Razor engine namespace not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a created a normal windows console self host app with AspNetCore but cant get the views to be loaded. Whenever Razor engine tries to render a page an error is returned indicating missing multiple namespaces e.g

> The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> using System;

I tried adding project.json with

```
{
  "buildOptions": {"preserveCompilationContext": true }
}
```

but still same result.

Comment: Can you post the dependencies on your `project.json` file?

Comment: Also you can check at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35832362/bcl-classes-not-found-when-rendering-view-in-asp-net-core-1

Comment: there are no dependencies in file , as i said its normal windows console app not net core console app. All dependencies added with NuGet.I am not even sure if it should actually use project.json at all.

Some of the errors 

Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

Comment: Are you using this: http://razorengine.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: no i use the engine provided by AspNetCore

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces have all been changed for `ASP.NET Core`

`ASP.NET Core` has removed the dependency on the `System` namespace. If you see it in your project your are looking and `ASP.NET 4` or earlier code and you will get compilation errors.

The `Razor` namespace is now located in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor` namespace.

If you are upgrading from an earlier `ASP.NET` version to `ASP.NET Core` then I would suggest using the default project template as a starting point as there are a lot of changes.

Comment: As i said i dont use no Core project template. I create a new Console app and adding AspNetCore from nuget.My project dont even have a project.json file. The code itself dosent show anything missing and i get Web Api and MVC calls to the controllers correctly. The only problem is when views are rendered by Razor those exceptions are outputted instead of the rendered view.